# How to invert a matrix with 100 trillion elements?

Tags: matrix, cudalink, inverse

I have a $10^{7}\times 10^{7}$ matrix with the following properties:

- it is *sparse*
- it is *gamma-5*
- it is *almost Hermitian*.

If $M$ is the matrix we are trying to invert, we know $M=A M^{\dagger} A$ and $A^{2}=I$.

**How can I invert it with Mathematica?**

Note: Since the matrix is sparse the inverse will be dense. Right now I'm trying to thrust::cuda, but it's having issues. I'm sure that Mathematica is probably not capable of doing this calculation.

Comment: What is a *gamma-5* matrix?  Surely you don't mean the $4 \times 4$ Dirac matrix $\gamma^5$.

Comment: Since "the inverse will be dense" how would you have enough memory to store the result even if you could compute it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have petabytes of storage.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork it satisfies the Clifford algebra.

Comment: [The hell of a doghouse](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51f1tOA2x-L.jpg)

Comment: @M.R. Shouldn't you have cured cancer or something with that? :-O

Comment: Would it be possible to give us the construction of a smaller matrix with the same properties?  (So that those of us without a terraflop cluster can play around with the problem.)

Comment: This would be an appropriate question to post on April 1.

Comment: Step 1 -- buy a computer with 10^16 bytes of RAM.

Comment: @m_goldberg Step 2 - Fill for chapter 11

Comment: M.R.: "I have petabytes of storage." WAT

Comment: Starting from scratch, why are you trying to invert it in the first place? As there may be alternatives...

Comment: http://vixra.org/pdf/1408.0048v1.pdf

Comment: @blochwave the matrix reference in the paper was amusing. The general algorithm, though, is what is really useful.

Comment: @rcollyer it's amazing what Google can throw up sometimes!

Comment: the matrix is gamma5 hermitian. Gamma5 (in four dimensions) is a specific matrix, and a matrix being Gamma5 hermitian means that it satisfies M = Gamma5 M^dagger Gamma5, where dagger is the hermitian adjoint